# Java: How to grab the next new "box"?

Tags: java, oop

I am very new to OOP. I'm finally slowly grasping the concept of it. But I am stuck on how to grab the next new "box" of type Question from my Quiz class. I don't even know how to explain it and am probably missing proper terminology. But here is my code.

I have two classes: Question and Quiz

```
public class Question{

   String question;
   public Question(String placeQuestion){
   question = placeQuestion;
   }
}

public class Quiz{
private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

   public void setQuestion(String q){
   Question setQ = new Question(q);
   questions.add(setQ);
   //each time here I create a "box" of Question class that has a String question in it 
   }
   public Question getNextQuestion(){
   //here I want to get the next "box" Question class with the String question 
   //in it. How do I track the current question "box" and go to the next one?        
   }
}
```

So how do I go to the next Question class "box" in the quiz class? For example, I have 20 questions. I want getNextQuestion to return the Question "box" of question 2 if I'm at 1. Or actually how do I even know I am at question 1 "box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class Question {
    String question;
    public Question(String placeQuestion) {
        question = q;
    }
}

public class Quiz {
    private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private int qindex=0;

    public void setQuestion(String q){
        Question setQ = new Question(q);
        questions.add(setQ);
        //each time here I create a "box" of Question class that has a String question in it 
    }
    public Question getNextQuestion(){
        Question q = questions.get(qindex);
        qindex++;
        return q;
    }
}
```

Mind you, you need to do more work than this - for example checking the length of the ArrayList before you call questions[qindex].

Comment: thank you see sharper i think you mean Question q = questions.get(qindex); because it's an arraylist? So I'm having a hard time picturing this. Can you explain how (i'm thinking a for loop style) if another class calls getNextQuestion it will have "box" 5 for question 5? If that makes sense.

Comment: Ha - I'm a C# programmer actually ;) They're so similar I can usually get away with answering easy Java questions. ArrayList<> and List<> in C# can take an index. Anyway, so the private field qindex stores which question we are up to. Every time getNextQuestion is called, that variable gets incremented (qindex++), keeping track of where you're up to. To improve the code, we could return null once we get past the last item.

Comment: Perhaps you have a usage in mind which my answer doesn't take into account - namely multiple classes calling the same instance of Quiz, each being up to a different place in the quiz? If so, we'd need to do this differently. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No that makes perfect sense! It's only the one class that will call getNextQuestion. I am going to use your suggestion of returning null once passed the last item. Thanks so much See Sharper, you've definitely cleared things up for me!!